# How much do the rules of Neverwinter Nights 2 differ from the original Pen&Paper D&D 3.5 rules? What are the core differences?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Some of my friends are going to start playing [*Neverwinter Nights 2*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neverwinter_Nights_2) soon, and they have invited me to join. I've read that this video game (mostly) sticks to the *D&D 3.5e* rules, but I don't know how precisely and what the differences are.

I could read the guides for this game and compare it to *D&D 3.5*, but I really don't want to learn about what is BAB again, what are spell slots etc. I will not be able to maintain concentration for a long time while reading this unless it is totally different, which is not, at least as I was assured.

**So, how much do the rules of *Neverwinter Nights 2* differ from the original Pen&Paper *D&D 3.5e* rules? What are the core differences?**

---

I've been thinking for quite some time whether this question belongs to here or to Arqade, because it is clearly a borderline case.

**[According to the only Meta discussion of this issue I've found](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4905/30214), when asking about video games based on Pen&Paper rules, the users are free to choose between RPG.SE and Arqade based on their understanding which expertise is more useful in their particular case.**

I've chosen RPG.SE for a simple reason. A video game expert who knows every single aspect of *Neverwinter Nights* but has also played some *D&D 3.5e* is probably likely not to spot some differences because of their general understanding of the *D&D 3.5e* system being weak.

At the same time, an RPG expert having a perfect affinity with *D&D 3.5e* who has even some short experience with the computer game based on it will spot the differences kind of easily, they will stand out. At least this was the case for me with *Vampire: The Masquerade -- Bloodlines*, a video game partially based on *Vampire: The Masquerade*, a Pen&Paper game.

Comment: I think you misread the meta. This question is inherently about something exclusive to the video game. Those are the things the meta reminds that are always off topic. Although an RPG expert might give a better answer than a video game expert, that’s misspplying that heuristic: the heuristic is whether an expert in *only* RPGs would give a better answer, which they wouldn’t. Simply, this **requires** video game expertise, and such questions are by definition off topic. (This May also be off topic at Arqade; I’m not sure. Even if so, that doesn’t make it on-topic here.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Expanding this logic would make this question also off-topic on Arqade, because it clearly requires a lot of RPG expertise. Does this mean that this question is ultimately off-topic on any SE?

Comment: Quite possibly. It’s a well-worn SE truism that not every topic has a site where it’s on-topic; its corollary is that there’s a forum for everything, so no need to struggle to make a question fit into SE.

Comment: Perhaps you can go to Arqade's meta and ask if this Q would be on-topic there? If it is, you could ask the mods to migrate it. If not, you can always ask [elsewhere](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go).